# function argument vs this performance

Tags: javascript, performance

In Javascript, which provides more performance:

1. Passing pointer to a large data structure as `argument` to a function

OR

2. Using `this` variable to get pointer in a class structure

Example:

Option 1:

```
function() {
    function(Ob) {
        // do something with Ob
    };
}
```

Option 2:

```
function() { // Class structure
    this.Ob = { foo: "bar" }; // bar is a big data structure 
    this.Fn = function() {
        var x = this.Ob
        // Use x 
    };
}
```

I find Option 1 to be more readable - but Option 1 becomes too verbose once your function needs a lot of variables.

Comment: Run some tests and find out.

Comment: Performance is likely different between different browsers and possibly even browser versions. Neither will make a big enough difference to matter in practice.

Comment: If the argument is an object, it's passed by reference by default. Therefore, it depends **what** you are dealing with. In the end, browsers implement JS engines in different ways. There is no official JS runtime, but all 3 popular JS execution engines are quite fast and these types of optimization make no sense. You are just wasting time. Use what's the most readable to you and your team (if you're in one).

Answer (score 1):

Your two examples differ in the scope.

Your first example, the inner function have the parent function scope, and it will be not accessible outside.

Your second example have the parent object scope, but you can access outside with the object instance:

```js
function parent() {
  
  function child() {
    // only accessible inside parent() function
  }
}

var parent = function() {
  this.child = function() {
    alert("Yeah");
  };
};
  
var p = new parent();
p.child(); // alerts Yeah
```

Comment: "_In Javascript, which provides more performance_" How is this answering the question?

Comment: Using vanilla objects is better performance, in terms of memory and cpu use of the browsers. However, performance is a subjective concept depending on tons of variables (cpu, ram, hd, browser, internet speed connection, operating system, etc).

Comment: In other words, the second example in the code is better.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, performance depends on browser and user PC ofc.
Both examples are almost the same.
First one can be faster, because you have direct reference on the object.
In other words, the less you use '.' the better performance you get. 
So:

```
this.Obj // do something
```

is slower than:

```
Obj // do something
```

but you will not notice the difference :)
If you want to find out more, try to get this book:
http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596802806.do

Comment: hey ! Thanks for the answer ! 

It makes sense when you think about what the underlying performance of C++